# How to Fit Conway–Maxwell-Poisson regression in R?

Tags: r, regression

I want to fit Conway–Maxwell-Poisson regression with one response and two randomly generated covariates in R, How I Fit?

```
library(COMPoissonReg)
  n1=200
  x1 = rnorm(n1,0,1)
  x2 = rnorm(n1,0,1)
 b0=0.05; b1=0.0025;b2=0.005;b7=0.0001
   
      y=b0+(b1*x1)+(b2*x2)
      y1=exp(y)
nu=exp(y)
  y2=rcmp(n1, y1,nu)
model = glm.cmp(y1 ~ x1+x2,formula.nu=x1+x2)
```

I found the following error
Error in formula.default(object, env = baseenv()) : invalid formula
so guide me I Fit this model?

Answer (score 0):

For your data above, you did not simulate the overdispersion parameter so you can don't specify the formula for nu. This will work, but your dependent variable is not an integer, so it throws an error:

```
glm.cmp(y1 ~ x1+x2)
```

You can simulate data like this, below comes with an over dispersion so you can see that in the estimate for nu :

```
n1=200
x1 = rnorm(n1,0,1)
x2 = rnorm(n1,0,1)
b0=0.05; b1=3;b2=2
   
mu=exp(b0+(b1*x1)+(b2*x2))
y = rnbinom(length(mu),mu=mu,size=1)

glm.cmp(y ~ x1+x2,data=df)
```